# Callgrind Profile Format inclusive/self cost

Tags: profiling, file-format, kcachegrind, callgrind

I'm trying to understand the Callgrind Profile Format. I found the [online description](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/show.cgi/KcacheGrindCalltreeFormat)

I thought I understood it fairly well until I encountered the 'Extended Example':

```
events: Instructions

fl=file1.c 
fn=main
16 20 
cfn=func1 
calls=1 50 
16 400 
cfl=file2.c 
cfn=func2 
calls=3 20 
16 400

fn=func1 
51 100 
cfl=file2.c 
cfn=func2 
calls=2 20 
51 300

fl=file2.c 
fn=func2 
20 700
```

The description reads: *One can see that in "main" only code from line 16 is executed where also the other functions are called. Inclusive cost of "main" is 420, which is the sum of self cost 20 and costs spent in the calls.*

How can the inclusive cost of 'main' be 420, when the self cost of only func2 is already 700?

Answer (score 1):

OK, the description is wrong: when i paste this example and open it in kcachegrind, indeed it shows a total inclusive cost of 820. That makes sense. Sorry for the noise.